# django LBForum TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django

i use virtualenv, django 1.3.1 and LBForum (0.9.22) cms

I need help how to correct the mistake?

Thanks in advance

Template error
In template /root/Dev/LBForum/ghlbforum/lbforum/templates/lbforum/inc_header.html, error at line 5

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''lbforum_index'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
![error page][1]
![error page][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the LBForum urls in your project's main URL file?

https://github.com/vicalloy/LBForum#id7

```
(r'^attachments/', include('attachments.urls')),
(r'^', include('lbforum.urls')),
```

NoReverseMatch error is thrown when there is no URL pattern with a matching tag in the urls.py file

Comment: Which version to use in django?

Comment: If you are running the Django test server, try going to a invalid url. Maybe [link](127.0.0.1:8000/a). The 404 page will show you all the calculated patterns. If a pattern with the name "lbforum_index" does not exist then the urls are not being included properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
yes, i use

urls.py file

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^attachments/', include('attachments.urls')),
    (r'^', include('lbforum.urls')),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ghlbforum.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^ghlbforum/', include('ghlbforum.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: you should edit the question. Not make it an answer.